# Is there any way to fetch the data from new relic and send it to API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, newrelic, aws-api-gateway, newrelic-platform

Suppose some issues found in new relic. I want to create a JIRA ticket by calling lambda function through API Gateway. So is there any way to call API Gateway from new relic app?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Relic can be integrated with AWS EventBridge using Webhooks. So if something happens an event is triggered in EventBridge and from that point on the sky is the limit. You could simply trigger a Lambda with that event and then process the issue from there.

https://newrelic.com/blog/nerdlog/new-relic-connect-aws-event-bridge